# Regex expression for timestamp with or without leading zero?

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with Regex.

This is a sample timestamp: `00:00:00.00` (Hour, Minutes, Second.Decimal). I also want this value to match `00:0:0.00` Notice that the leasing zero is optional in the center.

I was using this: `[1-60]:[1-60]:[1-60].[1-100]`, but that requires no leading zero. I would like help with making a SINGLE regex that works for both of the things listed above.

A complete solution would be fantastic, but if you could just point me in the right direction, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Note: `[1-60]` doesn't do what you expect. It is equivalent to `[1234560]` as character classes (and the `-` operator in them) work on *characters* and has no concept of a "numeric range" beyond that.

Comment: I don't get it: do you want to match 1 to 60 for the *hour* field? See the accepted answer, [it does exactly that](https://regex101.com/r/UFA1Kn/1). Try [`^(?:[10]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\.\d{1,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/UFA1Kn/2) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution won't actually match what you've described; it will only match a single digit in the sequence `0123456` in each position. You probably want something like

```
[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\.\d{1,2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern has a number of other problems. `[1-60]` is a character class. It will match a single `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, or `0` character. Secondly, the `.` in your pattern matches *any* character not just a literal `.`.

I think what you're looking for is something like this instead:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

This will match any one or two digits, followed by a literal `:`, followed by any one or two digits, followed by a literal `:`, followed by any one or two digits, followed by a literal `.`, followd by any one or two digits.

Or to check match only particular ranges of each time component, you can use a pattern like what [*chrylis*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690178/1715579) suggests, although I'd generally recommend actually parsing the time value if you really need to do this.

Comment: He's also wanting validation on the range (no 75 minutes).

Comment: @chrylis Yes I was working on updating my answer with something like that when I saw your answer and comment. Your solution looks like almost exactly what I was about to recommend (except that the last `:` should be a `\.`). Rather than duplicate your pattern I simply chose to include a note about parsing the date rather than using regex for validation.

Comment: *sigh* Stupid error; fixed. I am fascinated by the constant barrage of regex questions on here; this sort of thing doesn't *seem* that insurmountably hard.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you could do:

```
(?:\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

Regular expression:

```
(?:              group, but do not capture (2 times):
 \d{1,2}         digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times)
  :              ':'
  ){2}           end of grouping
   \d{1,2}       digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times)
   \.            '.'
    \d{1,2}      digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times)
```